# Regex for decimal with 1 digits before decimal sign 2 after decimal sign

Tags: regex

I've tried the below but it's not working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
^[0]{1}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: You only match `0` with `[0]`. Use `^[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[0]{1}` pattern matches a single `0` character. It does not make sure there are no digits before or after it and `[0]` will always match a single `0`, thus `{1}` is redundant.

If you need to match any 1 digit at the start of the string, followed with a dot, and then with any 2 digits, you need to use

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Note that it matches `0.00`, `1.00` .. `9.99`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xhFykw/1).

**Details**

- `^` - the start of string anchor
- `[0-9]` - any 1 ASCII digit
- `\.` - a dot
- `[0-9]{2}` - any 2 (due to the limiting quantifier `{2}`) digits
- `$` - end of string anchor.